# Strategy for handling hierarchical pages with empty parent content

Tags: posts, pages, urls, content, cms

Let assume I have the following page structure

```
/about-us (used as a parent holder only)
/about-us/history (real page)
/about-us/team (real page)
/about-us/industry (real page)
```

There is no content in the page "**about-us** ", but it is needed for two purpose

1. Allow hierarchical structure in url
2. Allow hierarchical structure in menu

But one of the issue is when user type "**/about-us**" then they will enter a blank page with non content.

So, should I auto forward user to url say "**/about-us/history**" by default?

Or it is the common way of handling hierarchical pages?

Answer (score 5):

I am using two strategies here...

1) is simple redirection to first child (using menu order)
`page-redirect.php`

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Redirector
 * Description: Empty Holder (redirect page) 
 */


    $rp = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_parent'   => get_the_id(),
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'order'         => 'asc',
        'orderby'       => 'menu_order'
    ));

    if ($rp->have_posts())
        while ( $rp->have_posts() ) { 
            $rp->the_post(); 
            wp_redirect(get_permalink(get_the_id()));
            exit;
        }   
    wp_redirect(dirname(home_url($wp->request)));
    exit;
```

2) generating a menu on a parent with a links to children (as example of it - http://unu.edu/about)

Answer (score 3):

Create a new file called `page-parent.php` and enter the following code in your new file:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Parent Menu
 * Description: Redirects empty parent page to first child page
 */

# Parent menu goes to first child page
# askwpgirl.com/redirect-parent-page-first-child-page-wordpress
$child_page = get_pages( "child_of=" . $post->ID . "&sort_column=menu_order" );
if ( $child_page ) {
    $parent_page = $child_page[0];
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $parent_page->ID ) );
}
```

Then, place the `page-parent.php` in the root directory of your child theme, for example:

```
/wp-content/themes/child-theme
```

After that, you will see the new template `Parent Menu` in the *Template* option.

[image]

Save the parent menu with the new template and whenever tried to access the parent page directly, it will redirect to the first child page.